# Flutter ensure I have a value in Async/Await and init functions

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

How can I make sure I have a state variable available after an async function call? My belief is because `getValues()` is async, it should "wait" until moving on to the next line. Thus, `getValues()` shouldn't exit and `configValue()` shouldn't be invoked until after my call to `setState` has finished. However the behavior I'm seeing it that `values` is an empty array in my Widget.

```dart
  late List values = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getValues();
    configValue();
  }

  getValues() async {
    final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/values.json');
    final vals = await json.decode(response)['values'];
    setState(() {
      values = vals;
    });
  }

  void configValue() {
    // How to make sure I have values[0] here?
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `it should "wait"`. No, it shouldn't. That's actually what async is all about. It does it asynchronously. And that's why there is the `await` keyword. It makes you able to wait for them.

Comment: Asynchronous functions return `Future`s, and `Future`s must be `await`ed (or have completion callbacks registered) to execute code when those `Future`s complete.  Additionally, you should avoid asynchronous initialization in `initState` and use `FutureBuilder`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your `getValues` to this:

```
Future<List> getValues() async {
  final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/values.json');
  final vals = await json.decode(response)['values'];
  return vals;
}
```

then create another middle function like this:

```
callasyncs() async {
   var result = await getValues();
   configValue(result);
}
```

and call it inside `initState` like this:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  callasyncs();
}
```

also change your `configValue` to this:

```
void configValue(List values) {
  // now you have updated values here.
}
```

here your both `configValue` and `getValues` are separated from each other and also your `configValue` will wait for the `getValues` result.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `await` before the method to complete the future. also can be use `.then`.

```dart
Future<void> getVids() async { //I prefer retuning value
  final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/values.json');
  final vals = await json.decode(response)['values'];
  setState(() {
    values = vals;
  });
}

void configValue() async {
  await getVids();
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```dart
List? values;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  getValues();
  configValue();
}

Future<void> getVids() async {
  final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/values.json');
  final vals = await json.decode(response)['values'];
  setState(() {
    values = vals;
  });
}

void configValue() {
  if (values != null) {
    if (values!.isNotEmpty) {
      …
    }
  }
}
```